# + keeps appearing in RStudio Console and won't run previous code

Tags: r, dictionary

I am trying to learn how to create maps with R. I'm just playing around with some code I see online but every time I run any line, the line that I ran shows up in my console, followed by a "+" underneath it. What does this "+" mean?

This is the code (from this site: https://www.molecularecologist.com/2012/09/18/making-maps-with-r/) :

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
map("worldHiresMapEnv","Canada”, xlim=c(-141,-53), ylim=c(40,85), col=gray90, fill=TRUE)
```

I've attached a photo that [shows the "+"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxKiC.png) I'm talking about, and also the error I get [if I try to run the code again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nDvc.png) after getting the "+"

I'm very new to R and trying to figure out how to navigate all the errors :)

Comment: Try `"Canada"` instead of `"Canada”`, be careful when copy-pasting. It should also be `col="gray90"` with quotes.

Comment: The + sign means the console expects you to finish your expression. This usually happens when you have a missing/incorrect symbol on one side (e.g. one side of the brackets missing). If you hit Esc, it going to end the expression and you can see what you're missing and edit it (in case of a very long expression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your " isn't a `"` recognized. The one at the end of Canada! Try this:

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
map("worldHiresMapEnv","Canada", xlim=c(-141,-53), ylim=c(40,85), col="gray90", fill=TRUE)
```